# My iPad has a popup saying I have a virus

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, virus

When I went to a website in Safari, it opened up another website with popups claiming my iPad has a virus.

I deleted some of my apps to try and get rid of the virus, but the popup keeps showing up every time I open Safari. Can someone help me?

[image: iPad virus popup]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the site including the pop-up? Also, why do you think you needed to delete some apps after seeing the pop-up?

Comment: Apple should block popups containing "award", "reward" and "virus". Probably some more too.

Comment: @ardaozkal even better don't allow popups to act modally always allow the user to be able to close a page

Comment: @Mark Yup, this is [the solution they went for in iOS 9.3](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/40i3wq/ios_93_preview_including_night_mode/cyud17d/).

Answer (score 12):

You likely do not have a virus.
It's probably just a popup that gets launched every time you re-open Safari.

Go to:

Settings > Safari > "Clear History and Website Data."

You won't lose any bookmarks, it will just clear your browser history and open tabs.

Let us know if that works for you!

Comment: *The "Clear" method also will remove any tracking cookies or temp-files left by the ad.

Answer (score 9):

Like [sleepdeficit said](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211343/72620), it's probably just a popup that appears every time you launch a page, but there's a way to get rid of it without losing your history and open tabs.

1. Force close Safari.
2. Turn off Wi-Fi (and cell service, if you have it).
3. Reopen Safari and, since the page can't load, you won't get the popup.
4. Close the tab that gave you the popup.
5. Turn Wi-Fi (and cell service) back on.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

It's almost certainly a javascript popup, not a virus. You can get rid of it by temporarily disabling Javascript.

Go to Settings -> Safari -> Advanced, and turn off Javascript. Now, go back to Safari and close that page so that it won't keep automatically opening. Finally, go back to the Settings and turn Javascript back on.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 9.3, JavaScript popups are no longer completely modal — you can still interact with the browser UI. Tap the tab button to open the list of tabs and tap the × to close the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that such popups generally open up from clicking/ tapping on useless and tricky buttons, one can also install content blockers or ad blockers from the App Store and enable them in Safari settings.

I sometimes use [Adguard](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-ios/overview.html) when I know that the site will show ads.

Also,

> Some popups and ads have fake buttons that resemble the close button, so use caution if you try to close a  pop-up or ad. If you're unsure, avoid interacting with the popup or ad and close the Safari window or tab.

From https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT203987

And [Avoid phishing emails, fake 'virus' alerts, phony support calls, and other scams](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204759) has some tips from Apple too.

Answer (score -2):

I just got the same message on my iPad did what you asked but got this
Virus have been detected on your Apple iPad
Your Apple iPad has been infected with virus because of recent adult sites that you have Visy. It will soon corrupt your SIM card data photos and contacts if no action taken
Then there is a counter
 Then to remove press on remove blue button then it has a timer clounting down 
It recognised I turned off internet 
I have put on the flight mode it has finished the count down nothing happened then the pop up “turnoffaeroplane mode or use wifi to access data” 
I have not visited any of those sites I was I. The health sites

Answer (score -3):

I would make sure your software is up-to-date to the latest version of iOS that the iPad 2 can run. Also, close your windows, and relaunch Safari. Hope this helps.